# Array con dos columnas en R

Tags: array, r

Tengo un dataframe que tiene cuatro columnas: record, time, V1, y V2. Necesitaría convertirlo en un array con dimensiones dim=c(3,10,2). Esto sería 3 ids (ID1, ID2, ID3), 10 tiempos (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) y dos variables (V1,V2).
Estos son los datos

```
mydata<- structure(list(record = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1","ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID2", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3", "ID3"), time = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8), V1 = c(33113, 33113, 150, 150, 150, 150, 275, 150, 150, 4897788, 33113, 95657, 1144, 642891, 518, 150, 73669, 403230, 450555, 33113, 2524740, 150, 3096225, 12628, 134896, 1202, 171157), V2 = c(29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 37, 28, 24, 29, 2495, 14, 14, 14, 25, 24, 29, 33, 30, 19, 29, 29, 29, 17, 20, 29, 20, 39)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(28:183, .Names = c("28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175","176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183"), class = "omit"))
```

Como podéis ver tengo missing en algunos de los tiempos (ID1 o ID2 NA en 8; ID3 NA en 9). Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar necesitas completar los casos que te están faltando:

```
datos_esperados <- expand.grid(record=unique(mydata$record),
                               time=unique(mydata$time))

datos_esperados %>% 
  left_join(mydata,
            by = c("record", "time")) %>% 
  arrange(record, time) -> datos_completos
```

Con `expand.grid()` armamos todas las combinaciones de `record` y `time`, luego con un `left_join()` con tus datos, completamos con `NA` las observaciones faltantes de cada grupo. El siguiente paso es intercalar de a 10 observaciones las columnas `V1` y `V2` para lograr transformar todo en un array con las dimenciones esperadas

```
m <- c(rbind(matrix(datos_completos$V1, nrow = 10), matrix(datos_completos$V2, nrow = 10)))
array(m, dim=c(10, 2, 3))


, , 1

       [,1] [,2]
 [1,] 33113   29
 [2,] 33113   29
 [3,]   150   29
 [4,]   150   29
 [5,]   150   29
 [6,]   150   37
 [7,]   275   28
 [8,]   150   24
 [9,]    NA   NA
[10,]   150   29

, , 2

         [,1] [,2]
 [1,] 4897788 2495
 [2,]   33113   14
 [3,]   95657   14
 [4,]    1144   14
 [5,]  642891   25
 [6,]     518   24
 [7,]     150   29
 [8,]   73669   33
 [9,]      NA   NA
[10,]  403230   30

, , 3

         [,1] [,2]
 [1,]  450555   19
 [2,]   33113   29
 [3,] 2524740   29
 [4,]     150   29
 [5,] 3096225   17
 [6,]   12628   20
 [7,]  134896   29
 [8,]    1202   20
 [9,]  171157   39
[10,]      NA   NA
```

Nota: la función de intercalación de vectores esta tomada de la respuesta de [Akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318244/6836377)

Comment: con esto me quedaría el array sin las dimensiones correctas. Yo necesito dim=c(3,10,2) 3 IDs, 10 times y 2 variables

Comment: Y es así como quedó el array, hay tres "grupos" (dim 3) que corresponden a cada ID, dentro de estos hay una matriz de 10 x 2, (dim 10, 2).  A menos que no sea un array lo que estás buscando.